# Anyone know of any real systems using Computational Semantics with Lambda Calculus?

Tags: nlp, lambda-calculus, first-order-logic

I was wondering if Computational Semantics is actually used in any real-world system?  (Simple examples [here](http://courses.washington.edu/ling571/ling571_fall_2010/slides/compsem_lambda.pdf) and [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.124.9969&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).  I would like to see how an actual system works.

> It seems like there are a bunch of issues with actually using Computational Semantics in any real world system:
>
> - It seems just labeling sentences with part-of-speech tags is error prone.
> - But you also need a reliable parse tree which is error prone and there can be many valid trees for one sentence.
> - Finding what pronouns are referring to what entities is error prone.
> - Word disambiguation is also another source of errors and multiple meanings could be valid in the same context.
> - Any context-free-grammar of English I can find seems to be incomplete.
>
> Finally, after all these sources of error are dodged, we can finally convert the sentence to FOL with Computation Semantics!

Also, I can't seem to figure out how to deal with prepositions in Computation Semantics.

Is this really just an academic exercise or is Computational Semantics actually useful?

Answer (score 0):

There are several better aproaches to natural language than simple lambda calculus and context free grammars, ie. HPSG, Montague Grammar, TAG, ...

Word disambiguation can be handled by Markov chains, for example.

Siri, Google Now, Cortana and IBM Watson are some examples for real world systems.

Google Translate is another application that uses Computational Semantics.

Comment: Watson seems to use a kitchen sink approach (pipeline of 100+ various IR/NLP techniques).  For machine translation statistical and end-to-end deep learning techniques are dominating.  Grammars seem like another rule-based system that has generally failed in AI.  I think Computational semantics is an academic exercise that may be useful one day when we can successfully do symbolic reasoning reliably.

Answer (score 0):

I believe (bu't don't quote me on this) that the technology spun out of the now-defunct Natural Language Theory and Technology group at the Palo Alto Research Center (PARC, formerly Xerox PARC), utilizes the lambda calculus to provide inferences about textual entailments. idk i only worked there a summer (freshman, so was wonderfully igorant of most of the goings-on there).

Anyway, that 'technology' was developed over 30 years and then Powerset bought the right to all of it for $15 million, attempting to disrupt smart search in general. Then Bing's fatass came along, gobbled it up nom nom nom, then continued devouring the entire research group as whole. The principal core investigators now work solely as adjuct profs at Stanford. Sad.